# SparkR Error: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hdfs, sparkr

I'm trying to initialize SparkR but I'm getting a permissions error. My Spark Version is spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6. I have searched for this error and how to solve it and I have found several related topics. However, I'm not able to solve it using the same approach that in those topics, the solution they give (and the one I tried) is giving permisions to the /tmp/hive directory using the following command:

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive
```

Can anyone with enough knowledge give me another possible solution?

The error stacktrace is the following one:

```
$ sudo ./bin/sparkR

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Launching java with spark-submit command /opt/cloudera/parcels/spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit   "sparkr-shell" /tmp/RtmpecLPo8/backend_port4be122057a03 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/12/19 12:53:17 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/12/19 12:53:17 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/12/19 12:53:23 ERROR RBackendHandler: getOrCreateSparkSession on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:40)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.setSparkContextSessionConf(SQLUtils.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.getOrCreateSparkSession(SQLUtils.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils.getOrCreateSparkSession(SQLUtils.scala)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1059)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwx------
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 75 more
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1062)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:70)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.sca
```

The result of hadoop fs -ls /tmp:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /tmp
Found 5 items
drwxrwxrwx   - hdfs      supergroup          0 2017-12-19 14:47 /tmp/.cloudera_health_monitoring_canary_files
drwxr-xr-x   - yarn      supergroup          0 2017-11-07 12:36 /tmp/hadoop-yarn
drwx--x--x   - hbase     supergroup          0 2017-09-07 10:44 /tmp/hbase-staging
drwx-wx-wx   - josholsan supergroup          0 2017-12-19 13:09 /tmp/hive
drwxrwxrwt   - mapred    hadoop              0 2017-09-12 09:34 /tmp/logs
```

Thanks you so much in advance!!!

Comment: @cricket_007 answered you in an answer due to the comment format

Comment: How did you configure Spark? Did you touch any hdfs-site.xml file? Are you sure it's reading the same HDFS file system?

Comment: As far as I can remember I haven't touched any hdfs-site.xml. Where is this file located by default?

I'm using Cloudera and I think that Spark version in cloudera does not support SparkR, so I downloaded the latest Spark version in my cluster gateway and executed it by default... may be that I have to change some configuration in this downloaded Spark to point to my cluster's HDFS?
How could I check this? @cricket_007

Thanks you so much for your help once again.

Comment: The SparkR binary exists even if not supported.  But anyway, did you make sure to download the version that doesn't include hadoop?

Comment: Also, you don't need sudo to run it. That won't change how Spark reads HDFS

Comment: @cricket_007 I will check that I download the version without hadoop and if not, I will do it and come back with the results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your error permissions do not match the output of the file system, sounds like you downloaded Spark but didn't configure it, therefore it's defaulting to local disk

First, try using `spark-shell` alone from CDH installation to run a smoketest.

I think Cloudera includes SparkR (they just don't officially support it). I don't see a reason why they would remove it from the installation.

> My Spark Version is spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.6.

You downloaded the version that includes hadoop (based on the end of the filename). Since you say you set it up on your cluster, you should use the download option without precompiled Hadoop. And unless it's actually a Cloudera parcel, don't place it in that /opt/cloudera/parcels directory.

Then, once you have that, extract it somewhere, and open conf/spark-env.sh (copy the template to this file)

Update the values to at least contain the same information as the other Spark installation that come with CDH

Ensure `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` points at the configuration directory of Hadoop on your system. `/etc/hadoop/conf/`

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 in fact in my Cloudera's Spark bin folde there's no SparkR, but anyways, following your solution I downloaded the Spark-without-hadoop version. After that I copied spark-env.sh from Cloudera's Spark to the new downloaded Spark and modified a few things to point to the right Spark path, and finally it worked. So thanks you so much for your help, I'm marking your answer as solution. Thanks you so much once again.